anime.js elements enter from bottom and animate vertically up out of viewport
Using anime.js how can targeted DOM elements be animated to enter the viewport from the bottom, move vertically upward, and exit the viewport off the top? Is a timeline required or a simple anime() call would suffice?
For example, see the iOS chat bubble animation at the bottom of this page. This example is built with Framer Motion. What is the equivalent in anime.js?
